# Python Xpath URL image

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

So i am trying to pull thumbnails from Youtube and example of where i am getting this form is here:

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=funny

so the xpath finds the link for each image, which is what i am looking for, but when running it through python it says "NO image" python for some reason cannot see the xpath even though i can see it right after it crashes if i do a test.

```
try:
    thumbnail = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ol/li/ol/li[1]/div/div/div[1]/a/div/img/@src").text
except NoSuchElementException:
    print "NO image"
    thumbnail = 'n/a'
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Marked as duplicate but question it was a duplicate of no-longer exists.

Answer (score 5):

Get all `img` tags in the "results" div, then use `get_attribute()` to get the `src` attribute value:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=funny')

for image in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="results"]//img[@src]'):
    print image.get_attribute('src')

driver.close()
```

Prints:

```
https://i4.ytimg.com/vi/cKhqUOncefY/mqdefault.jpg
https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/6-JDfR8x55E/mqdefault.jpg
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7KU8leAQat4/mqdefault.jpg
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/R7ghDhpCLKM/mqdefault.jpg
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VxvDVhjALoU/mqdefault.jpg
...
```

Comment: Will i be able to attribute the information taken from listing #1 with thumbnail #1 this way is just going to pull all of the images.

Comment: @BubblewrapBeast yup, `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="results"]//img[@src]').get_attribute('src')`.